# Loop in array return wrong number of array

Tags: javascript

I've this function that return me a group of array. Each array contain a list of teams. If the teams are more than 4, the result of array not is equal for each of it. In the example below, with 12 teams, it return me 12 array in total, 3 with 12 teams and 9 with 8 teams ( 3 teams are missing during the loop on each array, after the 3rd ). If i add only 4 teams, it work. How i can fix that ?

```
let teams = ["Team_1", "Team_2", "Team_3", "Team_4","Team_5", "Team_6", "Team_7", "Team_8","Team_9", "Team_10", "Team_11", "Team_12"];
    
teams = teams.map(id => ({id}));

teams.forEach(team => team.enemies = teams.filter(enemy => enemy !== team));
    
const matches = [];
    
while(teams.some(team => team.enemies.length)) {
  const playing = [];

  for(const team of teams){
    if(playing.includes(team)) continue;
    const enemy = team.enemies.find(enemy => !playing.includes(enemy)); 
    if(!enemy) continue;
    const indexTeam = team.enemies.indexOf(enemy)
    const indexEnemy = enemy.enemies.indexOf(team)
    
    team.enemies.splice(indexTeam,1);
    enemy.enemies.splice(indexEnemy, 1);
    
    playing.push(team, enemy);
  }
    
  if(playing.length) matches.push(playing.map(t => t.id))
}
    
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Please clearly state what is the desired output. Your question is too vague to understand what's required.

Comment: My expected output is to have all array in matches ( array ) with the same number of teans ( in that case 12 teams per array ). Actually it return me the right values only if the matches setted at begining is 4/8/16... , but if I add 10 or 12 teams , the output for each array is wrong, only the first 3 array are correct, the others array in the loop  will have less teams inside, and not is what i want.

Comment: The code is correct. Your logic is wrong. In the first 3 rounds each team has an opponent. After the third round this algorithm doesn't find an opponent for 4 teams because all possible opponents are already assigned to a different team. You have to start over with a better algorithm.

Comment: Simple example with 6 teams. First round: team 1 <=> team 2, team 3 <=> team 4, team 5 <=> team 6. Second round: team 1 <=> team 3, team 2 <=> team 4, team 5 <=> ???, team 6 <=> ???. That doesn't work because the only free option for team 5 is team 6 but they are already assigned in the first round.

Comment: Yes you are right, but in that case the team5 and team6 will can have a 2nd round ( team 6 vs team 5 ) and in that case for this round the team 6 is home and team 5 away. But in the next round i will have the same issue for last 2 teams